# Red triangle on google plus +1 button

Tags: jsp, web, liferay, google-plus, google-plus-one

My GooglePlu +1 button does not work. It is generated by Liferay's JSP page.

If I press `+1`, then it thinks for a while, then button turns to red triangle, then Google popup flashes for a moment, then it disappears and nothing happens.

Count does not increase.

[image]

No any error message appears elsewhere, including Google Chrome console.

The code of JSP follows:

```
    <%
String plusOneDisplayStyle = "medium";

if (displayStyle.equals("vertical")) {
    plusOneDisplayStyle = "tall";
}
%>

<liferay-util:html-bottom outputKey="taglib_ui_social_bookmark_plusone">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
        {
            lang: '<%= locale.getDisplayLanguage() %>'
        }
    </script>
</liferay-util:html-bottom>

<!-- version 201312090039 -->
<g:plusone
    data-count="<%= !displayStyle.equals("simple") %>"
    data-href="<%= url %>"
    data-size="<%= plusOneDisplayStyle %>"
>
</g:plusone>
```

**UPDATE**

Replacing with HTML5 version didn't help (the behavior is exactly the same).

Comment: The usual cause of this is Google's server not being able to fetch and parse the page you are trying to +1. Without having the URL to look at, it's hard for use to help debug.

Comment: I have tried mostly simple URL like MYSITE/html/try.html, where I put simplest button code (without explicit `href`). This one does not wotk too. May be the reason is that my site is `https`?

Comment: @Dims Is your site online or just on localhost?

Answer (score 2):

The Google crawler must be able to connect to your site and retrieve the share snippet from the URL. In addition to what you can [learn from the snippet documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/), ensure the following:

1. Your URL in your data-href is resolvable by the crawling. Is it a fully qualified URL with protocol (http or https), hostname, and path? Or is it relative to the current URL?
2. The crawler cannot retrieve non-public URLs, this includes `localhost`, intranet pages, and pages that are protected behind a login system.
3. Test the URL with the [structured data testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) to see if it works with that tool. This tool isn't the actual crawler so something are not discovered by it but it can help with some issues such as which snippets are being used.
4. Try using cURL or wget to simulate the crawler and examine the response that your URL is sending to the crawler. The following is an example command:

   ```
   curl -v -S -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20110814 Firefox/6.0 Google (+https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)" -X GET http://example.com/test
   ```

   This command simulates the crawler by specifying the crawler's user agent. It will output any errors as well as the response that is returned from the URL at the end of the command. If this command fails with a `HTTP 404` you likely have an issue with your URL format. If it fails with a `500` you likely have a server-side coding issue that you'll need to diagnose. A `400` or `401` means your server is wanting to authenticate the crawler and cannot.

The red triangle typically illustrates a communication failure between the crawler and your site. You might need to dig further into your server's configuration depending on what you determine above.

Comment: #3 reports that "server takes too long to respond", and #4 says that I have certificate problems, although GC and FF say I don't...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get your site *actually* online. Google has to be able to connect to your website to share the site with the public. You can either get your own server, or get a host to make a public url for you. ;)

Cheers!